# Are there known expressions for total variation distance between mean centered multivariate normal densities $N(0,\Sigma_{1})$ and $N(0,\Sigma_{2})$

Tags: st.statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains

Consider two mean centered multivariate normal densities $N(0,\Sigma_{1})$ and $N(0,\Sigma_{2})$.  Are there known expressions (as opposed to bounds provided by the Pinsker inequality) for the total variation distance between such densities?

Let $P_{1}=\Sigma_{1}^{-1}$ and $P_{2}=\Sigma_{2}^{-1}$. I am looking for either a general expression for the total variation distance or for expressions in special cases such as when (i) $P_{1}-P_{2}$ is positive definite or (ii) when $P_{1} =k P_{2}$ for some positive constant $k>1$. In special case (ii), the distance should be expressible using multivariate generalizations of the error function but I don't have a numeric approximation for the multivariate generalization of the error function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some work, I have come up with the following answer.

In the general case, the following holds for any two multivariate normal densities:
 \begin{array}{rcl}   f(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{1}) & \geq & f(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{2}) \\
&\Updownarrow & \\
-\frac{1}{2} x^{T} \mathbf{P}_{1}x + \frac{1}{2} log [|\mathbf{P}_{1}|] & \geq &  -\frac{1}{2} x^{T} \mathbf{P}_{2}x + \frac{1}{2} log [|\mathbf{P}_{2}|]   \\
&  \Updownarrow & \\
x^{T}[ \mathbf{P}_{1}-\mathbf{P}_{2} ]x   & \leq &    log [|\mathbf{P}_{1}|]    - log [|\mathbf{P}_{2}|]
\end{array}

The set $A:=\{x| f(x|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma_{1}})\geq f(x|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{2})\}$ is a compact and convex set if $\mathbf{P}_{1}-\mathbf{P}_{2}$ is a positive definite matrix as in special cases (i). Moreover, if $\mathbf{P}_{1} = k \times \mathbf{P}_{2}$ for $k>1$ then

$ \begin{array}{rcl}   f(x|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{1}) & \geq & f(x|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{2}) \\
&\Updownarrow & \\
x^{T} \mathbf{P}_{1} x   & \leq &   \frac{k}{k-1}  n \times log [k ]  \\
&\Updownarrow & \\
x^{T} \mathbf{P}_{2} x   & \leq &   \frac{1}{k-1}  n \times log [k ]. 
\end{array}
 $

In [A Generalized Error Function in n-dimensions](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/401722.pdf/),  M. Brown defines an n-dimensional generalized error function $erf_{n}(.): \mathbf{R}_{+} \rightarrow  \mathbf{R}$ by

$   erf_{n}(x) =  \frac{\int_{0}^{x} e^{-u^{2}} u^{n-1} d u }{\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u^{2}} u^{n-1} d u}  $

Equation [47] in the paper concerns diagonal variance-covariance matrices and states that

$Prob[\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_{i}^{2}}{\sigma_{i}^{2}} \leq \beta^{2}]  = erf_{n}(\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2}}). $

If this equations extends to the general case so that

$ Prob[ x^{T} \Sigma^{-1} x  \leq \beta^{2}]  = erf_{n}(\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2}}) $

then the total variation distance under special case (ii) can be expressed as

$\begin{array}{rcl} ||f(.|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{1})  - f(.|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{2})||_{TV} & = & erf_{n}(\frac{\sqrt{ \frac{k}{k-1}  n \times \ln [k ]}}{\sqrt{2}})  -  erf_{n}(\frac{\sqrt{ \frac{1}{k-1}  n \times \ln [k ] }}{\sqrt{2}}).  \end{array}  $

As per the [Brown paper](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/401722.pdf/), the error function is given specifically by

$   erf_{2m}(x)   =   1 -e^{-x^{2}}[1 + \frac{x^{2}}{1!} +\frac{x^{4}}{2!} + \ldots+\frac{x^{2(m-1)}}{(m-1)!}] $ if $n$ is of even dimensions and by 
$erf_{2m+1}(x)    =   erf_{1}(x) -\frac{e^{-x^{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}}[\frac{(2x)0!}{1!} + \frac{(2x)^{3}1!}{3!}  + \ldots+\frac{(2x)^{2m-1}(m-1)!}{(2m-1)!}] $

if $n$ is of odd dimension.

Considering the one-dimensional case and letting $k=(1+\epsilon)^{2}$, we get

$ \begin{array}{rcl} ||f(.|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{1})  - f(.|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{2})||_{TV} & = & erf_{1}(\frac{\sqrt{ \frac{k}{k-1} \times \ln [k ]}}{\sqrt{2}})  -  erf_{1}(\frac{\sqrt{ \frac{1}{k-1}  \times \ln [k ] }}{\sqrt{2}})  \\
& = & erf_{1}(\frac{\sqrt{ \frac{(1+\epsilon)^{2}}{(1+\epsilon)^{2}-1} \times \ln [(1+\epsilon)^{2} ]}}{\sqrt{2}})  \\
& &  -  erf_{1}(\frac{\sqrt{ \frac{1}{(1+\epsilon)^{2}-1}  \times \ln [(1+\epsilon)^{2} ] }}{\sqrt{2}}) \\
& = & erf_{1}(\frac{(1+\epsilon) \sqrt{ \frac{1}{\epsilon(2+\epsilon)} \times 2\times \ln [(1+\epsilon) ]}}{\sqrt{2}})  \\
& &  -  erf_{1}(\frac{\sqrt{ \frac{1}{\epsilon(2+\epsilon)}  \times 2 \times \ln [(1+\epsilon) ] }}{\sqrt{2}}) \\
& = & erf_{1}(\frac{(1+\epsilon) \sqrt{   \ln (1+\epsilon) }}{\sqrt{\epsilon(2+\epsilon)}})  \\
& &  -  erf_{1}(\frac{ \sqrt{   \ln (1+\epsilon) }}{\sqrt{\epsilon(2+\epsilon)}})
 \end{array}  $

which corresponds to one of the [answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156946/are-there-known-expressions-for-total-variation-distance-between-n0-sigma-12?rq=1) to a univariate version of this question.

The above can be partially extended to all of special case (i) to provide a bound on the total variation distance in terms of error functions.

Define a function $g_{1}(.): A \rightarrow \mathbf{R}_{+}$ by $g_{1}(x)=x^{T}P_{1}x$.   Let $b_{1} =\max_{x\in A}  g_{1}(x)$. Since $A$ is a compact convex set and the function $g(.)$ is continous, this maximum is well defined under the present assumptions. We we can hence define a set $A_{1}^{*}:=\{x \in \mathbf{R}^{n}| x^{T}P_{1} x \leq b_{1}\}$. Clearly, $A \subseteq A_{1}^{*}$.

Similarly, define a function $g_{2}(.): A \rightarrow \mathbf{R}_{+}$ by $g_{2}(x)=x^{T}P_{2}x$ and define a parameterized family of sets $A_{2}(.) : g_{2}(A) \rightarrow \mathbf{R}_{+}^{n}$ by $A_{2}(b)=\{x \in \mathbf{R}^{n}| x^{T}P_{2} x \leq b\}$.   Let $A_{2}^{*}= \{x \in A|A_{2}(g_{2}(x)) \subseteq A)\}$ and $b_{2}=\max_{x\in A_{2}^{*}}  g_{2}(x)$.  This maximum exists under the present assumptions since the set $A_{2}^{*}$ can be shown to the non-empty, convex, and compact.  Clearly, $A_{2}^{*} \subseteq A$.

We can now provide a bound for the total variation distance in terms of error functions that generalizes the expressions for the total variation in special case (ii):

$ \begin{array}{rcl} ||f(.|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{1})  - f(.|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{2})||_{TV} & = & \int_{x \in A} f(x|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{1}) dx  -\int_{x \in A} f(x|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{2}) dx \\
& \leq  & \int_{x \in A_{1}^{*}} f(x|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{1}) dx  -\int_{x \in A_{2}^{*}} f(x|\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_{2}) dx \\
& = & erf_{n}(\frac{\sqrt{ b_{1}}}{\sqrt{2}})  -  erf_{n}(\frac{\sqrt{b_{2} }}{\sqrt{2}}).  \end{array}  $

In special case (ii), $b_{1}=\frac{k}{k-1}  n \times \ln [k]$ and $b_{2}=\frac{1}{k-1}  n \times \ln [k]$.

While not generally available in closed form solution, increasingly good estimates for $b_{1}$ and $b_{2}$ can be generated through repeated simulation from centered multivariate normal densities with precision matrices $P_{1}-P_{2}$.   To generate estimates for $b_{1}$ and $b_{2}$, let $B=\{x^{(i)}\}_{i=1}^{L}$ be a set of (non-zero) random draws from a mean centered multivariate normal with precision matrix  $P_{1}-P_{2}$. For each $x^{(i)} \in B$, define

$\begin{array}{rcccccl}
t(x^{(i)}) &= &  \sqrt{\frac{log [|\mathbf{P}_{1}|]    - log [|\mathbf{P}_{2}|]}{(x^{(i)})^{T}[ \mathbf{P}_{1}-\mathbf{P}_{2} ]x^{(i)} }}  & , & \tilde{x}(x^{(i)}) & =  & t(x^{(i)}) \times x^{(i)}  \\
\tilde{b}_{1}(x^{(i)})  &= &  ( \tilde{x}(x^{(i)}))^{T} P_{1}\tilde{x}(x^{(i)}) & , & \tilde{b}_{2}(x^{(i)}) & =  &  ( \tilde{x}(x^{(i)}))^{T} P_{2}\tilde{x}(x^{(i)}) \end{array}$

and estimate $b_{1}$ and $b_{2}$ by 
$\hat{b}_{1}  =   \max_{x^{(i)} \in B}\tilde{b}_{1}(x^{(i)})$   and $\hat{b}_{2} =   \min_{x^{(i)} \in B}   \tilde{b}_{2}(x^{(i)}) $ respectively.

As the number of draws from the multivariate normal density increase, $E[\hat{b}_{1}] \rightarrow b_{1}$ and $E[\hat{b}_{2}] \rightarrow b_{2}$ where the former convergence is from the below and the latter from above.

Answer (score 2):

If you're content to know the answer up to constant factors, it is $\Theta(\min\{1,\|\Sigma_1^{-1}\Sigma_2-I\|_F\})$, where $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm; see https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.08693